# Google Drive API Issue iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-drive-api

I have successfully integrated the [Google Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/ios/quickstart) with iOS, however there seems to be a major issue with the Drive OAuth process: There's no button for the user to press to resign the `ModalViewController` to enter in this code....

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Google really was an absolute pain in the ass this time around. They made a mistake in their example code:

For anyone else trying to do this in the future, add `[viewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];` to the following method:

```
// Handle completion of the authorization process, and updates the Drive service
// with the new credentials.
- (void)viewController:(GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch *)viewController
      finishedWithAuth:(GTMOAuth2Authentication *)authResult
                 error:(NSError *)error
{
    if (error != nil)
    {
        [self showAlert:@"Authentication Error" message:error.localizedDescription];
        self.driveService.authorizer = nil;
    }
    else
    {
        self.driveService.authorizer = authResult;
    }
}
```